# How to update two tables in one statement in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I want to update two tables in one go. How do I do that in SQL Server 2005?

```
UPDATE 
  Table1, 
  Table2
SET 
  Table1.LastName='DR. XXXXXX', 
  Table2.WAprrs='start,stop'
FROM 
  Table1 T1, 
  Table2 T2
WHERE 
  T1.id = T2.id
AND 
  T1.id = '010008'
```

Comment: It would help if you explained why.

Comment: I am afraid, SQL server 2005 doesn't support updating multiple tables in one query.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018535/why-oracle-not-support-for-multiple-table-updates-in-single-line

Answer (score 249):

You can't update multiple tables in one statement, however, you can use a transaction to make sure that two `UPDATE` statements are treated atomically. You can also batch them to avoid a round trip.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.LastName = 'DR. XXXXXX' 
FROM Table1 T1, Table2 T2
WHERE T1.id = T2.id
and T1.id = '011008';

UPDATE Table2
SET Table2.WAprrs = 'start,stop'
FROM Table1 T1, Table2 T2
WHERE T1.id = T2.id
and T1.id = '011008';

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Actually, I am updating records of these two tables from another temptable. temptable has link to table1 but not table2. How can i update the same record of Table2? How will i link it?

Comment: @unknown: Based on your comment, you would need to join across both Table1 and Table2 when you update Table2 if your update query needs the keys from a third table. Regardless of that, you still need to do two separate updates.

Comment: probably not related: this won't work on MYSQL because the update syntax for mysql is different. you'd have to go
UPDATE Table1 , Table2
  SET Table1.LastName = 'DR. XXXXXX' 
WHERE T1.id = T2.id

Comment: do we need to maintain primary key and foreign key relation between them

Comment: You should also put your update statements inside try/catch block to avoid partial update in case of an error. see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749719/sql-server-transactions-roll-back-on-error

Comment: Hi I'm a bit curious what is the rationale behind 1 statement only changes data in one table? Anyone knows? I suspect either ACID or relational maths? I don't think this is a System-wise limitation but rather a principle adopted by all vendors. Think about an update statement changes one PK field in table A but FK in table B, this is a huge challenge for integrity and atomicity.

Answer (score 117):

You can't update two tables at once, but you can link an update into an insert using `OUTPUT INTO`, and you can use this output as a join for the second update:

```
DECLARE @ids TABLE (id int);
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE Table1 
SET Table1.LastName = 'DR. XXXXXX'  
OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @ids
WHERE Table1.field = '010008';

UPDATE Table2 
SET Table2.WAprrs = 'start,stop' 
FROM Table2 
JOIN @ids i on i.id = Table2.id;

COMMIT;
```

I changed your example `WHERE` condition to be some other field than `id`. If it's `id` the you don't need this fancy `OUTPUT`, you can just `UPDATE` the second table for the same `id='010008'`.

Comment: This is the best answer and should be voted as the true answer to the original question. Thank you. It worked for me.

Comment: Is that `T1.field` supposed to be `Table1.field`?

Comment: If you wonder what does INSERTED in the "OUTPUT INSERTED.id" mean then look here: 
"INSERTED - Is a column prefix that specifies the value added by the insert or update operation. Columns prefixed with INSERTED reflect the value after the UPDATE, INSERT, or MERGE statement is completed but before triggers are executed." link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016

Answer (score 26):

Sorry,  afaik, you cannot do that.  To update attributes in two different tables, you will need to execute two separate statements.  But they can be in a batch ( a set of SQL sent to the server in one round trip)

Answer (score 16):

The short answer to that is no.  While you can enter multiple tables in the `from` clause of an update statement, you can only specify a single table after the `update` keyword.  Even if you do write a "updatable" view (which is simply a view that follows certain restrictions), updates like this will fail.  Here are the relevant clips from the MSDN documentation (emphasis is mine).

[UPDATE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

> The view referenced by table_or_view_name must be updatable and reference **exactly one base table** in the FROM clause of the view. For more information about updatable views, see CREATE VIEW (Transact-SQL).

[CREATE VIEW (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

> You can modify the data of an underlying base table through a view, as long as the following conditions are true:
>
> - Any modifications, including UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, must reference columns from **only one base table**.
> - The columns being modified in the view must directly reference the underlying data in the table columns. The columns cannot be derived in any other way, such as through the following:
>
>   - An aggregate function: AVG, COUNT, SUM, MIN, MAX, GROUPING, STDEV, STDEVP, VAR, and VARP.
>   - A computation. The column cannot be computed from an expression that uses other columns. Columns that are formed by using the set operators UNION, UNION ALL, CROSSJOIN, EXCEPT, and INTERSECT amount to a computation and are also not updatable.
> - The columns being modified are not affected by GROUP BY, HAVING, or DISTINCT clauses.
> - TOP is not used anywhere in the select_statement of the view together with the WITH CHECK OPTION clause.

In all honesty, though, you should consider using two different SQL statements within a transaction as per LBushkin's example.

**UPDATE:** My original assertion that you could update multiple tables in an updatable view was wrong.  On SQL Server 2005 & 2012, it will generate the following error.  I have corrected my answer to reflect this.

> `Msg 4405, Level 16, State 1, Line 1`
>
> `View or function 'updatable_view' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.`

Comment: While it is not possible to update a View object that will affect multiple tables, you can create [INSTEAD OF triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) which break the original into separate statements (affecting one table each): `INSTEAD OF
Specifies that the DML trigger is executed instead of the triggering SQL statement, therefore, overriding the actions of the triggering statements. INSTEAD OF cannot be specified for DDL or logon triggers.`

Answer (score 16):

This works for MySQL and is really just an implicit transaction but it should go something like this:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1, Table2 t2 SET 
t2.field = t2.field+2,
t1.field = t1.field+2

WHERE t1.id = t2.foreign_id and t2.id = '123414'
```

if you are doing updates to multi tables that require multi statements… which is likely possible if you update one, then another based on other conditions… you should use a transaction.

Comment: This anser is still relevant for other users.

Comment: @Kyselejsyreček this answer should be avoided at all costs. MySQL has enough quirks and smells, most of which are actually unsupported but retained to avoid breaking code that depends on those quirks. Upgrading can easily break them or result in unexpected behaviour and performance issues

Answer (score 9):

You should place two update statements inside a transaction

Answer (score 2):

You can write **update** statement for **one table** and then a **trigger** on **first table** update, which update second table

Answer (score 1):

For general updating table1 specific column based on Table2 specific column, this query works perfectly:

```
UPDATE table 1  
SET Col 2 = t2.Col2,  
    Col 3 = t2.Col3  
FROM table1 t1  
INNER JOIN table 2 t2 ON t1.Col1 = t2.col1
```

Answer (score -2):

From my perspective you can do this, its one to one update of two tables in SQL SERVER:

```
 BEGIN TRANSACTION

      DECLARE @CNSREQ VARCHAR(30)
      DECLARE @ID INT
      DECLARE @CNSRQDT VARCHAR(30)
      DECLARE @ID2 INT

      DECLARE @IDCNSREQ INT
      DECLARE @FINALCNSREQ VARCHAR(30)
      DECLARE @FINALCNSRQDT VARCHAR(30)
      DECLARE @IDCNSRQDT INT


      SET @CNSREQ=(SELECT MIN(REQUISICIONESDT.CNSREQ) FROM REQUISICIONESDT
          INNER JOIN 
              REQUISICIONES
                ON REQUISICIONESDT.CNSRQDT = REQUISICIONES.CNSRQDT AND REQUISICIONES.IDRQDT = REQUISICIONESDT.ID
           AND REQUISICIONES.CNSREQ = REQUISICIONESDT.CNSREQ AND REQUISICIONESDT.IDREQ = REQUISICIONES.ID
        WHERE REQUISICIONES.CNSRQDT = REQUISICIONES.CNSRQDT AND REQUISICIONES.IDRQDT = REQUISICIONESDT.ID)

      SELECT REQUISICIONES.CNSREQ, REQUISICIONES.ID, REQUISICIONES.CNSRQDT FROM REQUISICIONES
       INNER JOIN 
          REQUISICIONESDT
              ON REQUISICIONESDT.CNSRQDT = REQUISICIONES.CNSRQDT AND REQUISICIONES.IDRQDT = REQUISICIONESDT.ID
               AND REQUISICIONES.CNSREQ = REQUISICIONESDT.CNSREQ AND REQUISICIONESDT.IDREQ = REQUISICIONES.ID
        WHERE REQUISICIONES.CNSRQDT = REQUISICIONES.CNSRQDT AND REQUISICIONES.IDRQDT = REQUISICIONESDT.ID
    AND REQUISICIONES.CNSREQ = @CNSREQ

        UPDATE REQUISICIONESDT SET  REQUISICIONESDT.CNSREQ=NULL, REQUISICIONESDT.IDREQ=NULL
          FROM REQUISICIONES INNER JOIN REQUISICIONESDT
             ON REQUISICIONESDT.CNSRQDT = REQUISICIONES.CNSRQDT AND REQUISICIONES.IDRQDT = REQUISICIONESDT.ID
       WHERE REQUISICIONES.CNSRQDT = REQUISICIONES.CNSRQDT AND REQUISICIONES.IDRQDT = REQUISICIONESDT.ID
      AND REQUISICIONES.CNSREQ = @CNSREQ

        UPDATE REQUISICIONES SET REQUISICIONES.CNSRQDT=NULL, REQUISICIONES.IDRQDT=NULL
          FROM REQUISICIONES INNER JOIN REQUISICIONESDT
          ON REQUISICIONESDT.CNSRQDT = REQUISICIONES.CNSRQDT AND REQUISICIONES.IDRQDT = REQUISICIONESDT.ID
       WHERE REQUISICIONES.CNSRQDT = REQUISICIONES.CNSRQDT AND REQUISICIONES.IDRQDT = REQUISICIONESDT.ID
     AND REQUISICIONES.CNSREQ = @CNSREQ

       SET @ID2=(SELECT MIN(REQUISICIONESDT.ID) FROM REQUISICIONESDT
        WHERE ISNULL(REQUISICIONESDT.IDREQ,0)<>0)
     DELETE FROM REQUISICIONESDT WHERE REQUISICIONESDT.ID=@ID2


      SET @IDCNSREQ=(SELECT MIN (REQUISICIONES.ID)FROM REQUISICIONES
          INNER JOIN REQUISICIONESDT ON
        REQUISICIONESDT.CEDULA = REQUISICIONES.CEDULA AND REQUISICIONES.FECHA_SOLICITUD = REQUISICIONESDT.FECHA_SOLICITUD
         WHERE REQUISICIONES.CNSRQDT IS NULL AND REQUISICIONES.IDRQDT IS NULL)

        SET @FINALCNSREQ=(SELECT MIN (REQUISICIONES.CNSREQ)FROM REQUISICIONES
            INNER JOIN REQUISICIONESDT ON
        REQUISICIONESDT.CEDULA = REQUISICIONES.CEDULA AND REQUISICIONES.FECHA_SOLICITUD = REQUISICIONESDT.FECHA_SOLICITUD
         WHERE REQUISICIONES.CNSRQDT IS NULL AND REQUISICIONES.IDRQDT IS NULL)

         SET @FINALCNSRQDT=(SELECT MIN(REQUISICIONESDT.CNSRQDT) FROM REQUISICIONES
           INNER JOIN REQUISICIONESDT ON
          REQUISICIONESDT.CEDULA = REQUISICIONES.CEDULA AND REQUISICIONES.FECHA_SOLICITUD = REQUISICIONESDT.FECHA_SOLICITUD
           WHERE REQUISICIONES.CNSRQDT IS NULL AND REQUISICIONES.IDRQDT IS NULL)

          SET @IDCNSRQDT=(SELECT MIN (REQUISICIONESDT.ID)FROM REQUISICIONES
           INNER JOIN REQUISICIONESDT ON
         REQUISICIONESDT.CEDULA = REQUISICIONES.CEDULA AND REQUISICIONES.FECHA_SOLICITUD = REQUISICIONESDT.FECHA_SOLICITUD  
         WHERE REQUISICIONES.CNSRQDT IS NULL AND REQUISICIONES.IDRQDT IS NULL)

           UPDATE REQUISICIONES SET REQUISICIONES.CNSRQDT = @FINALCNSRQDT, REQUISICIONES.IDRQDT=@IDCNSRQDT FROM REQUISICIONES
            INNER JOIN REQUISICIONESDT ON
             REQUISICIONESDT.CEDULA = REQUISICIONES.CEDULA AND REQUISICIONES.FECHA_SOLICITUD = REQUISICIONESDT.FECHA_SOLICITUD
            WHERE REQUISICIONESDT.CNSRQDT = @FINALCNSRQDT AND REQUISICIONESDT.ID = @IDCNSRQDT 


ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score -6):

It is as simple as this query shown below.

```
UPDATE 
  Table1 T1 join Table2 T2 on T1.id = T2.id
SET 
  T1.LastName='DR. XXXXXX', 
  T2.WAprrs='start,stop'
WHERE 
  T1.id = '010008'
```