# Update 2 tables in one statement (MS SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-update, inner-join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to update two tables in one statement in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005)

I have an update statement. It Updates one field but inner joins on another table to complete the where clause. I am using MS SQL.

I am now trying to update a field on the joined table but cannot seem to do it. I have read that you can only update one table at a time. Is this true? Is there a way I can get around this?

Here is my statement

```
update tbl_calendardatebox
set 
tbl_calendardatebox.HeaderBgColour = @value,
tbl_calendarobjects.Saved = '0'

from tbl_calendardatebox db
inner join tbl_calendarobjects o on
db.ObjectId = o.Id

where o.PageId = @page
and o.GroupField = @group and o.GroupField <> '-1'
and o.Visible = '1'
and o.CanUserEdit = '1'
and db.HeaderBgColour <> @value
```

So the two tables are **tbl_calendardatebox** and **tbl_calendarobjects**. I get the error message on tbl_calendarobjects.Saved = '0' - *The multi-part identifier "tbl_calendarobjects.Saved" could not be bound.*

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You're giving aliasses to the tables, yet don't use them. Either you broke something when posting here or you'd never get the systax to work. I'm also not sure if it's even possible to update multiple tables in one statement, but this is one thing i can spot straight away atleast.

Comment: I'm giving fully qualified aliases on the sets because it wont pick up the aliases on the from.

Comment: See my answer, i've made queries like that so often i lost count. However never tried updating multiple tables, could work straight away though... Not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax fix to begin with, might solve the problem as well, untested!

```
update db
set 
db.HeaderBgColour = @value,
o.Saved = '0'

from tbl_calendardatebox db
inner join tbl_calendarobjects o on
db.ObjectId = o.Id

where o.PageId = @page
and o.GroupField = @group and o.GroupField <> '-1'
and o.Visible = '1'
and o.CanUserEdit = '1'
and db.HeaderBgColour <> @value
```

Actual answer found on stackoverflow: [How to update two tables in one statement in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005)

**This is NOT possible Sadly.**

Comment: Thanks but it's still coming up with the error on o.Saved = The multi-part identifier "o.Saved" could not be bound.

Comment: Ye, most likely can't do an update with a from clause when trying to do multiple tables. Try doing a variation on what Marco suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Updating multiple tables at the same time is not possible. Following is the abstract from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260662%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) which clearly shows

{} represents mandatory field

[] represents optional fields

[...n] represents 0 or more

**[See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)**

```
UPDATE 
        { 
         table_name WITH ( < table_hint_limited > [ ...n ] ) 
         | view_name 
         | rowset_function_limited 
        } 
        SET 
        { column_name = { expression | DEFAULT | NULL } 
        | @variable = expression 
        | @variable = column = expression } [ ,...n ] 

    { { [ FROM { < table_source > } [ ,...n ] ] 

        [ WHERE 
            < search_condition > ] } 
        | 
        [ WHERE CURRENT OF 
        { { [ GLOBAL ] cursor_name } | cursor_variable_name } 
        ] } 
        [ OPTION ( < query_hint > [ ,...n ] ) ]
```

Following section cannot contain any join. "{ }" represents mandatory field which can contain View Name or table name but not join.

```
{ 
 table_name WITH ( < table_hint_limited > [ ...n ] ) 
 | view_name 
 | rowset_function_limited 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this example (taken from [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,85813,85816#msg-85816)) can help you:

```
UPDATE a 
INNER JOIN b USING (id) 
SET a.firstname='Pekka', a.lastname='Kuronen', 
b.companyname='Suomi Oy',companyaddress='Mannerheimtie 123, Helsinki Suomi' 
WHERE a.id=1;
```

You query (I cannot test it, sorry) could be:

```
UPDATE tbl_calendardatebox cdb
  INNER JOIN tbl_calendarobjects co
    ON cdb.ObjectId = co.Id
SET cdb.HeaderBgColour = @value
  , co.Saved = '0'
WHERE co.PageId = @page
AND co.GroupField = @group 
AND co.GroupField <> '-1'
AND co.Visible = '1'
AND co.CanUserEdit = '1'
AND cdb.HeaderBgColour <> @value
```

Comment: Thanks Marco though it's throwing up syntax errors here. It's firstly throwing an error on cdb 'Expecting SET' which makes me believe that you cannot inner join before you SET.

Comment: Personally i think it has something to do with USING, i don't know the USING statement personally (which doesn't mean to much though!). Mind you, i know USING dbname to specify what DB you want to run the query on, but i dont know it while joining. I edited a variation of Macro's answer in my post, using a "normal" on statement.

Comment: Is this for MySQL? I forgot to mention, I am using MS SQL.

Comment: @F.B. ten Kate: I'm sorry, but it's the first time I try to use a multiple tables update and I don't know which the error could mean. I took a MySql example, maybe you're aven using a different db. Sorry again, I can't test queries at the moment...

Comment: I'm only talking about MS SQL Here, i dont work with MySQL so i can't say much there :) But since Codemonkey didn't specify your answer is perfectly valid.

Comment: F.B. is correct. You can't use `USING` here, the two fields in the JOIN have different names.

Comment: @codemonkey: Are you using SQL-Server (which version?) or Ms-Access?

Comment: You can't update 2 tables in one statement in SQL-Server: See this answer for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005/2044520#2044520

Comment: Aaawh! i just linked that aswell :(

But ye, impossible sadly.

Comment: Moreover..this goes same as constraints appies to updating a View

Answer (score 0):

Like Shantanu told, it isn't possible to update multiple tables.
Anyway, if your envirornment allow it, you could walk on procedure way.
It's safe and atomic. Remember, on catch an error, rollback always.