# What is wrong with this query ( multiple update table )

Tags: sql, sql-update

This actually makes my phpmyadmin stop working.

```
SET @admin_mail = "mail@mail.com";
--  5. SET ORDER MAIL

UPDATE 
sales_flat_order, 
sales_flat_order_address, 
-- sales_flat_order_status_history, 
sales_flat_quote, 
sales_flat_quote_address

SET 
sales_flat_order.customer_email = @admin_mail,
sales_flat_order_address.email = @admin_mail,
sales_flat_quote.customer_email = @admin_mail,
sales_flat_quote_address.email = @admin_mail;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot update multiple tables from one statement. You can enter multiple tables into a single SQL `UPDATE` statement like a `JOIN`, but you may only actually update values in one of the tables.

You will have to do this:

```
UPDATE 
 sales_flat_order
SET 
  sales_flat_order.customer_email = @admin_mail;

UPDATE
  sales_flat_order_address
SET
  sales_flat_order_address.email = @admin_mail;
```

etc...

Here is a good thread related to this: [How to update two tables in one statement in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005)