# Can I use update with inner join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update, c#-5.0

I want to use update for **any record and all records** of my table that `column1 <> column2`
my command is :

```
update table1 set name = (select name from table2
                           where code1 <> code2 and table1.id=table2.id)
```

Is it possible?

And is it possible to use inner join in update command?

Comment: [https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=sql+server+update+with+inner+join&oq=sql+server+update+with+inner+join](Google results for 'sql server update with inner join')

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update a table using JOIN in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply join both tables,

```
UPDATE  a
SET     a.Name = b.Name
FROM    Table1 a
        INNER JOIN Table2 b
            ON a.ID = b.id
WHERE   a.Code1 <> a.Code2
```