# Remove Duplicate Values from Field in MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, duplicates, duplicate-data

I'm after some help putting together a query to remove duplicate data in a specific field in one of my tables.

I have a table called contacts that I need to import in to another system. The new system requires that the email field be unique. I need a query that will allow me to search the email field and remove any duplicate data or set it to "".

I don't want to remove the rows, just the duplicate of the email. So if there are two records contain the email gaz@example.com, then I want to keep the first reference while removing the second.

Seems like this should be a simple thing to do but I'm struggling working our how to achieve it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a primary key on the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a query similar to the following:

```
UPDATE CONTACTS A, CONTACTS B
  SET B.EMAIL=NULL
WHERE A.EMAIL=B.EMAIL
  AND A.KEY_FIELD>B.KEY_FIELD
```

Use the field reference to determine which is removed.

Comment: Hi, thanks. What's the A and B bit for? I'm pretty green with SQL.

Comment: The A and B are aliases for the table - it allows you to join a table with itself and thus look for the duplicates.

Comment: Oh great, and finally what is the KEY_FIELD part?

Comment: There must be another column in your contacts table that determines which is the first email reference (for example, a row ID or maybe a timestamp for the insertion).  KEY_FIELD is my place holder for this column - you need to use whatever the suitable column in your table is.

Comment: well I have a unique id column and I tried with that but it said it didn't exist?

Comment: It's id, an auto_increment

Comment: I did UPDATE CONTACTS A, CONTACTS B SET B.EMAIL="" WHERE A.EMAIL=B.EMAIL AND A.ID>B.ID; and got a Unknown column A.ID.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34936/discussion-between-gaz-and-noz)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE CONTACTS SET b.email = ""
FROM CONTACTS a, CONTACTS b
WHERE a.EMAIL = b.EMAIL AND a.ID>b.ID
```

Another Possible solution

Reference :

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005
```