# replace text value from table1 to table2

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need replace values

```
Table dict_title
Column1 ENG - Column2 FIN
white       -    valkoinen
black       -    musta
2000+ words for replace

Table new_products
Column content
white phone
black phone
about 10000 records
```

Now i try do this query

```
UPDATE new_products , dict_title 
SET new_products.title = 
REPLACE (new_products.title, dict_title.eng, dict_title.fin)
```

But this query handle only first line of dict_title table. How i can do replace from all table?

Thank you

Comment: are you joining `new_products` and `dict_title` at all?  this is how you can write an `update` using two tables... it says mssql 2005 but it will work for mysql, too: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: How i can join? That tables doesnt have similiars id or something else...

Comment: Oh, then I don't understand your problem... maybe.  So....... for `new_products.title`, are you trying to replace every occurrence of `dict_title.eng` with its corresponding value of `dict_title.fin`?

Comment: The last query what worked i wrote. Could you write example what i can try more?

Comment: At this point, I'm not even sure what you are trying to do... I personally don't know how to do what I think you want to do without a stored procedure or running the same query multiple times.  Can you clarify what you want and if a stored procedure is an option?