# modifying a view containing two tables sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

learning the concept of views.
1)i created two tables and a view.
2) modified the e_id of a person in the view.

Expected result: want the id to be changed in the view as well as the tables.

Actual Result: the modified row got deleted from the view.
but the e_id was changed in one of the tabes

i created a simple table called emp_info( e_id,ename)
Tim 128
melissa 132

Table 2: mytab containing(desig,salary,doj,ssn,e_id)
Executive sales head    81000.9 1/10/2011   1003    128
Executive head kindle   99077.9 11/10/2011  1004    132

created a view vmytab

```
create view vmytab
as
select b.e_id,a.ename,b.desig from
mytab b,emp_info a
where a.e_id=b.e_id
```

I tried to change the employee id(E-ID) of melissa.

```
update vmytab set e_id=200 where ename='melissa'
```

i got the result (1 row(s) affected)

when i checked my view(`select * from vmytab`)
the whole row belonging to melissa was missing
only 1 record belonging to tim was there.

but when i checked mytab table,the e_id of melissa had been changed to 200.

i again checked emp_info. here the old record i.e melissa  132  was present.

can anyone explain the indiscrepensies or have i done anything wrong in the code?

Comment: Is it MySql or SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

When you updated the id in one table, the inner join in your view didn't return any rows. The record was updated (in the table you specified for that column in the view) but the ids didn't match any more.

You need to update both tables with the new id in this case (don't use the view to update).

Answer (score 0):

When you update a view in SQLServer You update only one of the table in your view:

> Any modifications, including UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements,
>   must reference columns from only one base table.

From [CREATE VIEW (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx)

Personally I never used view as shortcut to update a table, in your case you need to update two table, so the only way to do it is using two queries, but if you want to be sure that the update is happening at the same time for both table you can use a transaction, check here: [How to update two tables in one statement in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005)