# ASP.NET FormView Control, SQL Data Source - SQL Join Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sqldatasource

I have a Form View control connected to a SQL data source control with a Select inner join statement that reads the users profile information from from database1/table1 and pulls an email address column from database2/table2.

When a user clicks the Update button on the form view to update their profile information, I would like them to be able to update their email address which happens to be in database2/table2. All of the other data such as first name, last name etc is stored in database1/table1. What is the best way to do this? How would I form the Update statement?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: This question has been asked alady several times in the past. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005