# SQL Update statement syntax

Tags: mysql

I have two tables which I want to update using an SQL Update statement. These two tables contains a row named "oak" and "exp" which is the values I want to update. My best guess so far is this:

```
'UPDATE `items_woods`, `skills_woodcutting` SET `oak`=`oak`+1, `exp`=`exp`+13 WHERE `id`=?'
```

However, none of the values are saved in the database. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('

        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        UPDATE items_woods
        SET items_woods.oak = ´1´
        FROM items_woods T1, skills_woodcutting T2
        WHERE T1.id = T2.id 
        and T1.id = ´?´

        UPDATE skills_woodcutting
        SET skills_woodcutting.exp = ´1´
        FROM items_woods T1, skills_woodcutting T2
        WHERE T1.id = T2.id
        and T1.id = ´?´

        COMMIT


        ')) {
```

Comment: Is your `WHERE` clause actually finding anything to update?

Comment: Use a join if you want to UPDATE 2 tables

Comment: @MikeW yes, I am using prepared statements, and the questionmark is set to be 1. I tested the update statement with only updating one value and it worked.

Comment: @Mihai how would I implement it on my example? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update two tables in one statement in SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: `update t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.somecolumn=t2.someothercolumn SET t1.col=x,t2.col=y` This is for mysql

Answer (score 1):

SQL Update, will only update one table at a time

Use a transaction with two update statements

Comment: can you help me with the code above? I think I did precisely what was described in the other thread but it still does not work. Thanks.

Comment: @user3287771 Did it do anything? Did you get error message? YOu have two ? marks, need to pass two parameters (same value)

Comment: It did nothing but returning an error message that I have created myself if the statement doesn't go through. The two questionmarks should both be equal to 1 so I guess that should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

As there two tables, you must update them with two separate statements. It is possible to make these a single transaction, and committing both transactions only after both are successful.

I'm not sure what datbase you are working with, but the general approach would be:

```
commit   (start the transaction)
update items_woods set oak = oak+1 where id = ?
update skills_woodcutting set exp=exp+13 where id = ?
commit   (complete the transaction)
```

Comment: Your SQL is wrong, use BEGIN TRANSACTION, not COMMIT to start a transaction. Anyway it's a duplpicat equestion

Comment: In ORACLE you use a COMMIT or ROLLBACK to begin the transaction. As I mentioned in the post, the original poster did not specify the database. Thanks.

Comment: The first COMMIT just empties the already running (implicit or named) transaction. A new transaction is then started automatically with the very next statement. COMMIT does not actually start a transaction (ANSI or Oracle)

Comment: That's correct, the COMMIT effectively clears uncommited transactions. It is commonly used as a starting point for a new transaction. Rollback has the same effect, but of course reverses any uncommited work. Oracle applications use this technique extensively. So my SQL was not wrong, just another way to do the same thing as begin_transaction. Cheers.

Comment: While it works for you, it is not a good programming practice. Forcing acceptance and of close current transactions, without checking? Your sample code labels the command as if it starts a new transaction, it doesn't. It closes the current transaction. The next issued command starts a new implicit transaction

Comment: All of Oracle Ebusiness and PeopleSoft Applications are written this way. It is very rare to see a begin_transaction in their code. I agree with what you are saying, but am also pointing out that using a commit works and is commonly used.

Comment: PHP is commonly used too :-P