# How to Update Two tables with single statement in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, inner-join, sql-server-2005-express

I have two tables and I want to update both the tables with single Query

Sample query:

```
UPDATE T1, T2 SET T1.FirstName = T2.SecondName ,T2.SecondName = T1.FirstName
FROM Table1 T1, Table2 T2
WHERE T1.id = T2.id
```

Is there any mechanism for doing this in the Sql server

Comment: This is not possible. See question "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005" for more details.

Comment: [link]http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/04/30/sql-server-update-from-select-statement-using-join-in-update-statement-multiple-tables-in-update-statement/ try this link and see for better clarification

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update two tables in one statement in SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 1):

As I know you can not update two tables in one statement, but you can use transactions to create two separate update queries for both tables.