# How to alter a table (add a column) simultaneously when a row is added (column name = row id) in another table?

Tags: php, mysql

How to write code in MySQL such that when ever a row with a primary key id is added to a table, a corresponding column is added in another table such that the name of the column is equal to the id of the row just added.

I tried the following but to no use.

```
sqlQuery("INSERT INTO table1(name) VALUES('$name')");
$id = sqlQuery("SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()");
$id = mysqli_fetch_array($id);
$id = $id['id'];
sqlQuery("ALTER TABLE table2 ADD '$id' INT(2) NOT NULL");
```

sqlQuery - user defined function that return mysqli_query result.

Any help would be great.
Also, I'm a newbie. Sorry if this is a silly question to ask.

Comment: This stinks of bad design, and a complete lack of understanding of databases

Comment: Better read a bit about MySQL, and the difference between `'` and `\``

Comment: Why in the world would you need that.

Comment: @MarkBaker Sorry, but I'm new to MySQL and databases. Any help?

Comment: Why don't you just use mysql relationships?
http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561 What exactly is your goal and what are you trying to create? There are probably some better cleaner ways of getting your problem solved.

Comment: @Daan I'm making a website that takes allows people to make orders.
Orders involve name of the product and quantity.
First table lists all the products and their details like price.
Second table has the actual orders. Row with quantity.

Any better design?

Comment: Without knowing why you're doing it (what business requirement you're trying to solve) it's very difficult for anybody to advise you on how you should approach the problem

Comment: http://agiledata.org/essays/dataNormalization.html

Comment: Thanks..
My actual goal is to have a table that can list product and quantity ordered by the customers along with the details of the customer.
I have separate table listing details of all the products.

Comment: okay.. I'll do the reading. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'll do the reading. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to help. There are a lot of examples on the internet for what you are trying to make. Once you have learned how relational database work in MySQL you will be able to come up with the answers on your own.

Comment: okay... Thanks!
Also, would I need to learn how to update two tables simultaneously for this design? Are transactions necessary?

Comment: Take a look at this question  it already has some great answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 0):

Make it OOP style and there is a var in the class that automatically returns the last updated item.

```
$con = new mysqli(SQL_HOST, SQL_USER, SQL_PASSWORD, SQL_DATABASE); //do normal error checking with database connection
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1(name) VALUES('$name')";
$con->query($sql);
$sql2 = "ALTER TABLE table2 ADD '$con->insert_id' INT(2) NOT NULL"  //$con->insert_id is the parm you are looking for.
$con->query($sql2);
```