# Updating two tables in one SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to update my `Scout` and `ScoutRole` tables from one SQL query. I've tried to follow this example: [How to update two tables in one statement in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005).

But I keep receiving the error message

> The multi-part identifier "SR.Role" could not be bound

How do I resolve this?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE Scout
SET Scout.FirstName = @ScoutFirstName, 
    Scout.LastName = @ScoutLastName, 
    Scout.EmailAddress = @EmailAddress,
    Scout.ClubID = @ClubID
FROM Scout S, ScoutRole SR
WHERE S.ScoutID = SR.ScoutID AND S.ScoutID = @ScoutID

UPDATE ScoutRole
SET SR.Role = @ScoutRole,
    SR.Username = @Username,
    SR.Password = @Password
FROM Scout S, ScoutRole SR
WHERE S.ScoutID = SR.ScoutID AND S.ScoutID = @ScoutID

COMMIT
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Your joins are pointless, anyhow.  All you need to do is `where S.ScoutID = @scoutID` on the first and `where SR.ScoutID = @ScoutID` on the second.  \

Comment: `SET` clauses can't use aliases. `SET ScoutRole.Role =...` and what @marc_s said, many times over. I know the other question is using this style, but copy-pasting queries without understanding what they're doing is not a good idea.

Comment: Is it best to just do two separate queries in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be all you need to use:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE Scout
SET FirstName = @ScoutFirstName, 
    LastName = @ScoutLastName, 
    EmailAddress = @EmailAddress,
    ClubID = @ClubID
WHERE ScoutID = @ScoutID

UPDATE ScoutRole
SET Role = @ScoutRole,
    Username = @Username,
    Password = @Password
WHERE ScoutID = @ScoutID

COMMIT
```