# Update a column of one table with a column of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update one column of first table with another column of other table with this query:

I need to update the both columns at a same time.

```
update tblMTD 
set tblMTD.agedebt = OST.balance, OST.balance = '0'
from tblMTD 
inner join OST on tblMTD.sub = OST.sub
```

I get an error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The multi-part identifier "OST.balance" could not be bound.

Comment: If you're updating `tblMTD`, you cannot do a `SET` on a column from a second table in the same statement. `UPDATE` only ever applies to **a single table**. If you need to update two tables, then you need two `UPDATE` statements

Comment: but i want to update both tables in a single query, is there any procedure to update two tables at a same time in a same query.?

Comment: You ***cannot*** do that. Just can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
UPDATE tblMTD 
SET tblMTD.agedebt = OST.balance 
FROM tblMTD INNER JOIN OST ON tblMTD.sub = OST.sub
WHERE OST.balance = '0'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i want to update both at a same time with some conditions, i tried to run this query in two segments as : (update tblMTD 
set tblMTD.agedebt = OST.balance, OST.balance = '0'
from tblMTD inner join OST on tblMTD.sub = OST.sub) + (update tblMTD 
set OST.balance = '0'
from tblMTD inner join OST on tblMTD.sub = OST.sub)

Comment: but my condition fulfills in fist query, other query fails the condition aand updated the wrong field

Comment: where condition is :WHERE CAST(tblMTD.date as date) = CAST((SELECT MAX(date) FROM tblMTD where agedebt IS NULL) as date) AND tblMTD.invoiceamount > OST.balance

Comment: @Muhammad, You can't update multiple tables in one statement, however, you can use a transaction to make sure that two UPDATE statements are treated atomically. You can also batch them to avoid a round trip. Please see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005