# I need to update two table in single query

Tags: sql-server

I need to update two table in single query.

Please find the below query.

```
Update   
m_student_moreinfo 
INNER JOIN
  m_student 
ON
  m_student_moreinfo.studentID = m_student.id
SET m_student_moreinfo.MIAStartdate=GETDATE(),m_student.status='Clinical MIA'

where
  studentID IN
(
  Select 
    smi.studentID 
  FROM 
    dbo.m_student st
  INNER JOIN
    dbo.m_student_course sc
  on
    sc.studentID=st.id
  INNER JOIN
    dbo.m_student_classClinical  scl
  on
    scl.studentcourseID=sc.id
  INNER JOIN
    dbo.m_student_moreinfo smi
  on
    smi.studentID=st.id
  where 
    scl.startDate<=GETDATE() and scl.endDate >=GETDATE()
      and MIAStartdate IS NULL
)
```

I am getting Incorrect syntax near `Inner`.

Comment: You can not update two tables in a single query. You will have to do it in two update statements.

Comment: that error is from the inner join next to the update. It is not possible to update 2 tables in one statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can't update two tables at once, but you can link an update into an insert using OUTPUT INTO, and you can use this output as a join for the second update
please see [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/eab6e48d-d22a-4e1f-add6-aaf3b47bdd84/how-to-update-multiple-tables-in-sql-server-2008-?forum=transactsql) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005) for more info

So basically  you can wrap this in transaction and commit after all update steps finished.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: **You can not.**

What you can do is two update queries in a transaction:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
update query 1
update query 2
COMMIT;
```

That wil do the job for you

Comment: why not ? what is your constraint ?

Comment: Take a look at this thread: [Update a table using join in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server).  It might put some light on your problem of using a JOIN in an update query.