# how to join 2 table and update column the both together

Tags: sql, sql-server

table 1 :

```
idtb1 --pk
published
delete
```

table 2 :

```
idtb2 --pk
idtb1 --fk
published
delete
```

how to update 2 column `published` ,`delete` on 2 table together by command `Update`

Comment: You mean with one update statement?

Comment: AFAIK not possible

Comment: @AndyWiesendanger : yup!, ^^!

Comment: @avkkamsy Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't update more than one table in a single statement

```
       BEGIN TRANSACTION

       update A
       set A.published =  @published
       from table1 A 
       inner join table2 B on B.idtb1 = A.idtb1

      update B
      set B.published = @published 
      from table2 B 
      inner join table1 A on B.idtb1 = A.idtb1

      COMMIT
```

[This question already has an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005)