# Update two tables in a single query

Tags: sql, orientdb, nosql

How to update multiple tables in a orientdb using single query?

Looking for something like this

```
UPDATE table1, table2
    SET table1.col = a,
         table2.col2 = b
    WHERE table1.id = table2 .id;
```

Comment: You can't update multiple tables in one statement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update multiple tables in one statement, however, you can use a transaction to make sure that two UPDATE statements are treated atomically. You can also batch them to avoid a round trip.

Comment: Something more than a copy&paste from here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005