# how to edit joined data from databade in pdo php

Tags: php

failure to update data from join please team help me so as to update

```
 $result =  "UPDATE manager m INNER JOIN user u ON
          m.manager_phone='$manager_phone', m.manager_fax='$manager_fax', m.manager_email='$manager_email', u.fullname='$fullname', u.address='$address',
                u.occupation='$occupation' WHERE manager_id='$id'";

        $stmt = $connpdo->prepare($result);
        $stmt->execute();
       if ($stmt)
       {
           echo "ok";
           exit;
       }
       else
       {
           echo "fail";
           exit;
       }
```

Comment: Unfortunately you can only update one table per statement. Take a look at this question for reference:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: You can update more than one table per update statement, depending on your database.  What database are you using?

Comment: Did my answer help you get to where you were going?

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is malformed and there is no SET statement.  Is this what you wanted?

```
  $result =  "UPDATE manager m 
          INNER JOIN user u ON m.manager_id = u.user_id
          SET m.manager_phone='$manager_phone', 
          m.manager_fax='$manager_fax', 
          m.manager_email='$manager_email', 
          u.fullname='$fullname', 
          u.address='$address',
          u.occupation='$occupation' 
          WHERE manager_id='$id'
  ";
```