# How to update three or more tables using single sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on an asset management system, and i am stuck.
I want to update about 3 tables in one single query connected by some common id columns!

```
UPDATE assets 
JOIN asset_types ON assets.asset_type_id = asset_types.asset_type_id,  
JOIN assignment_station ON assets.assignment_station_id=assignment_station.assignment_station_id,
JOIN asset_statuses ON assets.asset_status_id = asset_statuses.asset_status_id
SET
assets.asset_type_id = 1,
assignment_station.assignment_station_name ='Foxdale Court',
assignment_station.assignment_station_manager ='John Dole',
assignment_station.assignment_station_manager_number = '09887765433',
asset_statuses.asset_status_id =3
WHERE assets.asset_id=1
```

[image]

But I cant seem to find any answers on stackoverflow or google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update two tables in one statement in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: As currently written, this doesn't relate to PHP or mysqli. Does your query work and you are having issues implementing in PHP/mysqli?

Comment: MySQL should support that syntax.  What issue are you having?

Comment: The error is simply the entire query thrown back without any specific line or syntax error

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile i did check. Its not a duplicate. Kindly look at how many tables i want updated.

Comment: @user3783243 as my habit, i usually try in phpmyadmin/Heidisql if my queries work, before adding them to my php files.

Comment: So the query works in your UI but only fails in the PHP implementation? If so please add the PHP to the question, also show how you are handling the errors.

Comment: *the entire query thrown back without any specific line or syntax error* ... I have not seen but am very curious on such a raised error. After you post relevant PHP code block, please also post the entire error message or whatever shows in console, web page, or log file.

Comment: 'UPDATE assets 
JOIN asset_types ON assets.asset_type_id = asset_types.asset_type_id,  
JOIN assignment_station ON assets.assignment_station_id=assignment_station.assignment_station_id,
JOIN asset_statuses ON assets.asset_status_id = asset_statuses.asset_status_id
SET
assets.asset_type_id = 1,
assignment_station.assignment_station_name ='Foxdale Court',
assignment_station.assignment_station_manager ='John Dole',
assignment_station.assignment_station_manager_number = '09887765433',
asset_statuses.asset_status_id =3
WHERE assets.asset_id=1'

Comment: @Parfait, i run my queries in phpmyadmin before adding them to my php code

Comment: Here is a link to the error i got in phpmyadmin [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/aedb0f9fb9efdc811211634384c0630620190321062603/7a6ead105f594a633538473632190cf920190321062603/13790c)

Comment: @user3783243 the action of my form calls a php file that runs the update query, but like i mentioned, i test my queries in phpmyadmin before proceeding to add it to my php code. So if it doesnt work in phpmyadmin console, i dont add it to my php file.

Comment: So the query doesn't work in your DB UI either? `here is a link to the error i got in phpmyadmin` sounds like query fails in DB, before you should be putting it in PHP. I can't see the error. Please update the question with the error (as text, not an image). Also if that code you posted as a comment is different than the above code please add it to the question as well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff kindly see my prevous comments on this thread. I have resorted to use separate update statements to update my tables for the time being, but i would like to find out if i could do that with one query to update more than 3 tables.