# SQL multiple table update issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to update two tables at the same time. The action completes successfully.However, it updates all records in the the table instead of the ones specified. I have tried the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005/5321193), but to no avail. Any ideas what the issue might be? My code looks like below.

```
$sql = "UPDATE $receiverTable, $currUserTable 
SET $currUserTable.originator = '$curr_username', 
$receiverTable.originator = '$curr_username', 
$currUserTable.status = '$currValue', 
$receiverTable.status = '$currValue' 
WHERE ($receiverTable.username = '$curr_username') 
OR ($currUserTable.username = '$curr_username')";
```

Comment: Tag appropriate database name.

Comment: @mkRabbani, I am not sure what you mean. Thanks

Comment: Which database engine are you using

Comment: I mean MSSQL or MySQL or Oracle ....

Comment: Thats a weird requirement, why not wrap two updates inside a single transaction ?

Comment: Also, it is unusual to be using variables for the table names (in fact, it is a potential vulnerability).  You should explain why you have this need.

Comment: @timBiegeleisen, the names are dynamically generated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no condition on your `JOIN` (you really shouldn't be writing JOINs with commas any more) and so every row gets JOINed to every other row, which means that they all have a JOIN to a row in which one of the `WHERE` conditions is true, hence they all get updated. Rewrite your `JOIN` with the appropriate condition and the problem will go away. Something like:

```
UPDATE $receiverTable
JOIN $currUserTable ON $currUserTable.somecolumn = $receiverTable.somecolumn
SET $currUserTable.originator = '$curr_username', 
$receiverTable.originator = '$curr_username', 
$currUserTable.status = '$currValue', 
$receiverTable.status = '$currValue' 
WHERE ($receiverTable.username = '$curr_username') 
OR ($currUserTable.username = '$curr_username')
```

If there is no way that the tables can be JOINed, you will need to write the UPDATE as two separate queries.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick. I was trying to do it without the JOIN!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing this with a single update use a transaction to wrap two update commands, something like [this](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/06/06/sql-server-update-two-tables-one-statement/).

```
BEGIN TRANSACTIONS;

UPDATE TABLE1
SET Col1 = 'SomeValue'
WHERE Cond1 = 'SomeCond';

UPDATE TABLE2
SET Col2 = 'SomeValue'
WHERE Cond2 = 'SomeCond';

COMMIT;
```

UPDATE

Following [this](https://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/transactions/) I believe with phpi it would look like:

```
mysqli_autocommit($dbConnection, false);

$query1 = " UPDATE $receiverTable set originator = '$curr_username', 
status = '$currValue' WHERE username = '$curr_username' "
$query2 = " UPDATE $currUserTable set originator = '$curr_username', 
status = '$currValue' WHERE username = '$curr_username' "

mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query1); 
mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query2);

mysqli_commit($dbConnection);
```