# UPDATE to multiple tables with one WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, where-clause

I need to update two tables with the same WHERE clause.   The WHERE clause has hundreds of IDs so I want to avoid writing it twice like this...

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET (values...)
WHERE ID in (list of IDs)

UPDATE TABLE2
SET (values...)
WHERE ID in (list of IDs)  -- this is the same statement as above
```

Is there a way to merge these with one WHERE statement?

Comment: No - one update statement will directly update only one table. Put your IDs into a temp table (or table variable) and then join to update.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update two tables in one statement in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: Per the linked SO answer, make sure to wrap your update statements in a `transaction` in order roll back the `update` if part of it fails for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not support multi-table updates.

You can, however, put these ids in a table, that you can then use in your queries.

```
create table id_table (id int);  -- or whathever datatype you need
insert into id_table (id) values (1), (2), ...; -- list of ids
```

Then:

```
update t
set ...
from table1 t
where exists (select 1 from id_table i where i.id = t.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this in SQL Server.  Your best bet is to create a temporary table:

```
select *
into toupdate
from values ( . . . ) v(id)
```

Then you can use this in the `delete` statements:

```
update table1
    set . . .
    where id in (select id from toupdate);
```

Comment: You mean I "can't" really do it?   And Update not delete right?