# roll back a batch is not easy?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

After two days tests on batch, roll back and try ..catch, my mind is still vague. I separate what I was doing into two step in order to clear my question.

**1. roll back a batch**
As online book explains, in a batch, executed statements cannot be roll back only except the batch is in a transaction and error in the batch cause the transaction is roll back.

So I put the batch into a transaction like

```
begin transaction
     create table  A ...
     insert into A values...
     insert into A values... (error here!)
     insert into A values...
     GO
rollback
```

This  works with error output and no table was created

```
(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'A'.
```

However, the rollback will be executed anyway even no error in transaction. In order to deal with this case, I use TRY ...CATCH as in 2.

**2. use TRY ...CATCH**

```
BEGIN TRY
   begin transaction
     create table  A ...
     insert into A values...
     insert into A values... (error here!)
     insert into A values...
     --GO
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
     ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

This time it doesn't allow statement GO here any more. S**o Batch  is whole block between `BEGIN TRY` AND `END TRY` in this case?**
  In addition, the result is not as I expected. The `CREATE TABLE` AND first insert were still executed and didn't roll back.
  I searched again. **It seems I need to `SET XACT_ABORT ON` in order to record these executed statement as uncommitted before touch commit. What I am understanding here is right?** If so, I didn't add any commit statement in this case.

By the way,  test are done on SQL SERVER 2012. Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server - transactions roll back on error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749719/sql-server-transactions-roll-back-on-error)

Comment: The GO in the first block is not needed as far as I know.

Comment: if remove GO, rollback cannot take effect, maybe because of latency of transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't allow the GO statement is that the try and catch must be part of the same batch as metioned in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179296(v=sql.105).aspx). It states;

> "Each TRY…CATCH construct must be inside a single batch, stored
>   procedure, or trigger. For example, you cannot place a TRY block in
>   one batch and the associated CATCH block in another batch. The
>   following script would generate an error:"
>
> ```
> BEGIN TRY
>     SELECT *
>         FROM sys.messages
>         WHERE message_id = 21;
> END TRY
> GO
> -- The previous GO breaks the script into two batches,
> -- generating syntax errors. The script runs if this GO
> -- is removed.
> BEGIN CATCH
>     SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber;
> END CATCH;
> GO
> ```

For an alternative idea on how to handle this, take a look at gbns answer on the question [Nested stored procedures containing TRY CATCH ROLLBACK pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2074139/685760) as he discusses his pattern/template for handling transactions including the use of (and reason for) XACT_ABORT and other nifty features. I'd also suggest reading the associated links in gbns answer

Aaron Betrand's answer to the same question refers to a Erland Somarsskog's [article on error handling](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling_2005.html) that is very similar to gbn's answer also.

Even though the title of the original question relates to nested transactions, it is still applicable in your situation I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SET `XACT_ABORT ON` in the begining of your script.

Check out `XACT_ABORT` MDSN reference page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx)