# I thought everything between BEGIN/COMMIT TRAN was considered 1 transaction that succeeds or fails?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here's my code. It's a very simple: the 1st `INSERT` fails while the last two succeed.

Before I go on, I want to clarify that I understand that I can plug in an `IF statement` with `@@ERROR` or `BEGIN ROLLBACK` that will solve the issue. I *know* how the issue can be solved.

Since both INSERTs in the script are between a `BEGIN/COMMIT TRAN`, I thought that this would be considered a single transaction. So in my case, since the 1st `INSERT` fails, then I assumed that the following `INSERT`s wouldn't executed or wouldn't be committed. It seems that's not the case.

Is the purpose of `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMIT TRAN` to be able to use a the `@@ERROR` function and/or `ROLLBACK TRAN` between them?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#testTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #testTable
create table #testTable
(
    Id int not null,
    Name varchar(100)
)

BEGIN TRAN T1;
insert into #testTable select null, 'Joe';
-- select @@ERROR
if @@ERROR = 0
BEGIN
    insert into #testTable select 1, 'Bob';
    insert into #testTable select 2, 'Ralph';
END
COMMIT TRAN T1;
select * From #testTable
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Table variables (`@testTable`) do **NOT** support transactions.

If you need transactional support, use a normal temp table (`#testTable`) instead.

Comment: Is there some documentation for this?

Comment: @roryap - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx "Because table variables have limited scope and are not part of the persistent database, they are not affected by transaction rollbacks."

Comment: Thanks, @SeanLange! (I was searching - you were finding :-) )

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks.

Comment: I changed to temp tables, but the last two `INSERT`s are done, even though the first one fails. I would still need to use `@@error`.

Comment: @rbhatup If you want to do things differently when there are errors you need to use try/catch.

Comment: @SeanLange, as I mentioned in my initial message, fixing the issue is not reason for the message. I thought that since it's between a BEGIN TRAN and END TRAN, it would be considered a single unit and either it all succeeds or all fails.

Comment: A transaction is NOT a try/catch block. When an error occurs in a block of code it will attempt to continue to the next  statement. This is why the try/catch was introduced in sql 2005.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I'm just saying that I thought a BEGIN/END TRAN was a way of taking several transactions (ie. INSERTS) and "converting" them into one unit that either succeeds or fails.

Comment: See the discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749719/sql-server-transactions-roll-back-on-error to see under what condition a transaction will roll back automatically (which is what I think you mean by single unit of failure).

Comment: @StuartAinsworth, thanks for the link. I guess my question should be that, if the block of code doesn't have a ROLLBACK, then there's no reason to use transactions.

Answer (score 2):

To make this series inserts an "all or nothing" situation you need to use TRY/CATCH

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#testTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #testTable
create table #testTable
(
    Id int not null,
    Name varchar(100)
)

begin try
    BEGIN TRAN T1;
        insert into #testTable select 1, 'Bob';
        insert into #testTable select null, 'Joe';
        insert into #testTable select 2, 'Ralph';
    COMMIT TRAN T1;
end try

begin catch
    select 'Error encountered. No rows added'
    rollback transaction
end catch

select * From #testTable
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments below and in the initial post, I understand how to fix the issue.

Comment: I'm just saying that I **thought** a BEGIN/END TRAN was a way of taking several transactions (ie. 3 `INSERT`S) and "converting" them into one unit that either succeeds or fails.

Comment: Apparently, the purpose of `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMIT TRAN` to be able to use a the `@@ERROR` function or `try/catch` to check for errors, and then `ROLLBACK TRAN`.