# Why is my transaction being rolled back automatically when INSERT INTO fails?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, transactions, rdbms

Surprisingly, I could not find any relevant explanation or documentation for this issue I'm having.

In the case of these SQL statements:

```
SELECT 1 AS Test INTO #tmpTest    
BEGIN TRAN    
SELECT 1 AS Test INTO #tmpTest    
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

When executed one by one, the `SELECT ... INTO` at line 3 fails, as expected, with message -

> There is already an object named '#tmpTest' in the database.

However, after that, the `ROLLBACK` statement in line 4 fails:

> The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN
>   TRANSACTION.

Even though the transaction *did* `BEGIN` successfully from line 2.

*I've seen [SQL Server - transactions roll back on error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1749719/3258851) but answers don't apply here because the default `xact_abort` is `off`. <sub>In addition, the [answer from Quassnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1749771/3258851) contradicts the [answer by Raj More](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1749780/3258851).</sub>*

What's the actual explanation?

Comment: I've tried and faced the same on SQL 2017. Interesting.

Comment: Using SQL Server 2016, I added a `SELECT @@TRANCOUNT` before and after the second `SELECT` statement, then executed line by line. The first one returned (as expected) `1`, then the `SELECT` failed, then the second `@@TRANCOUNT` returned `0`. _BUT_, wrap the bad `SELECT` in a try/catch, and there's still an open transaction going into the `CATCH` block. Fascinating.

Comment: I've managed to get this message: "Msg 3998, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Uncommittable transaction is detected at the end of the batch. The transaction is rolled back."

Comment: the other answer is more accurate than the one you accepted. Batch aborting is the key to the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: Guess you're right @MartinSmith.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html

What you are getting is a batch abortion in this case which leads to an implicit rollback. The blog is about SQL Server 2000 error handling, but most of it still remains valid.

Edit: A little more digging and found this which specifically mentions the case of trying to create a table that already exists :
http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#BatchTranAbort

Answer (score 2):

Per this Microsoft article: [XACT_STATE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/xact-state-transact-sql)

> (...) an error has occurred that has caused the transaction to be classified
>   as an uncommittable transaction. The request cannot commit the
>   transaction or roll back to a savepoint; it can only request a full
>   rollback of the transaction.

I run this first:

```
SELECT 1 AS Test INTO #tmpTest    
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT, XACT_STATE()
BEGIN TRAN    
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT, XACT_STATE()
```

Then:

```
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT 1 AS Test INTO #tmpTest    
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT @@ERROR, ERROR_MESSAGE()
    SELECT @@TRANCOUNT, XACT_STATE()
END CATCH
```

The `SELECT` in the `CATCH` block returned: "*There is already an object named '#tmpTest' in the database.*", `@@TRANCOUNT` is `1`, but `XACT_STATE` is `-1`, so the error message in SSMS states:

> Msg 3998, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Uncommittable transaction is
>   detected at the end of the batch. The transaction is rolled back.

The next `SELECT @@TRANCOUNT` returns `0`.