# Why the transaction insert 2 values when fails the first one?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I have this Table:

```
TableAB
{
    IDTableA;
    IDTableB;
}
```

I have one row in the table, (1,2). Now I want to insert some others values, and I want to do it in a transaction. I use this:

```
begin
insert into TableAB (IDTAbleA, IDTAbleB) VALUES(1,2);
insert into TableAB (IDTAbleA, IDTAbleB) VALUES(1,3);
insert into TableAB (IDTAbleA, IDTAbleB) VALUES(1,3);
commit
```

I get an error of integrity in the first insert, but the second and third insert, insert the values in the table.

How I am using a transaction and fails the first one, why does it insert the other two rows? I thought inside a transaction, if somethings fails, all is aborted. Then in this case, which is the difference to use the transaction and don't use it?

Thanks.

Comment: "I thought inside a transaction, if somethings fails, all is aborted." -- true for some (most?) DBMS. For SQL Server you may need to change the settings, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749719/sql-server-transactions-roll-back-on-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you should be wrapping things in a `TRY...CATCH`.

```
BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION InsertValues;
    INSERT INTO TableAB (IDTAbleA, IDTAbleB) VALUES(1,2);
    INSERT INTO TableAB (IDTAbleA, IDTAbleB) VALUES(1,3);
    INSERT INTO TableAB (IDTAbleA, IDTAbleB) VALUES(1,3);
    COMMIT InsertValues;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    ROLLBACK InsertValues;
    THROW;

END CATCH
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRY

    INSERT INTO TableAB(IDTAbleA,IDTAbleB)VALUES(1, 2);
    INSERT INTO TableAB(IDTAbleA,IDTAbleB)VALUES(1, 3);
    INSERT INTO TableAB(IDTAbleA,IDTAbleB)VALUES(1, 3);

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN

        IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            THROW;
        END
        ELSE IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
        BEGIN
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END;

    END;

END CATCH;
```

Read more:

**XACT_ABORT**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

**XACT_STATE()**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/xact-state-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

**@@TRANCOUNT**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trancount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `TRY` and `CATCH` and in the `CATCH` you have to `ROLLBACK` the transaction like already mentioned. The other way to do this is to `SET XACT_ABORT ON` as follows.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON 

BEGIN TRAN
insert into TableAB (IDTAbleA, IDTAbleB) VALUES(1,2);
insert into TableAB (IDTAbleA, IDTAbleB) VALUES(1,3);
insert into TableAB (IDTAbleA, IDTAbleB) VALUES(1,3);
COMMIT TRAN
```