# Deleting a SQL row ignoring all foreign keys and constraints

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a row in a table. This row has an ID column referenced in a few other tables with millions of rows. The SQL statement to delete the row always times out. From my design, I know the row I wish to delete is never referenced any where else. Hence I would like SQL to ignore having to check all other tables for a foreign key reference to this row and delete the row immediately. Is there a quick way to do this in SQL 2008?
Perhaps something along the lines of:

```
DELETE FROM myTable where myTable.ID = 6850 IGNORE CONSTRAINTS
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: Have you considered adding indices to the key-reference columns on the related tables? If not already present, this would allow SQL to rapidly determine whether any other rows reference the row you're attempting to delete - and may give you a substantial performance increase as well...

Comment: I can suggest another approach. In my system most (of hundreds) tables points to a dbo.Company.Id. Even deleting an empty company, with no references, just causes the DB to check FK integrity in billions of rows. Solution: Just use logical deletes.

Comment: Solution that worked for me on PostgreSQL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53057368/2097494

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can set the constraints on that table / column to not check temporarily, then re-enable the constraints. General form would be:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ConstraintName
```

Then re-enable all constraints with

```
ALTER TABLE TableName CHECK CONSTRAINT ConstraintName
```

I assume that this would be temporary though?  You obviously wouldn't want to do this consistently.

Comment: While the above is true, there are several considerations this should be done only for testing purposes and should be avoided in production scenarios.

Comment: It should be `WITH CHECK CHECK` (twice) otherwise you may run into "untrusted foreign key" issue https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/foreign-key-trusted/

Answer (score 23):

Yes, simply run

```
DELETE FROM myTable where myTable.ID = 6850
```

**AND LET ENGINE VERIFY THE CONSTRAINTS**.

If you're trying to be 'clever' and disable constraints, you'll pay a huge price: enabling back the constraints has to verify *every row* instead of the one you just deleted. There are internal flags SQL keeps to know that a constraint is 'trusted' or not. You're 'optimization' would result in either changing these flags to 'false' (meaning SQL no longer trusts the constraints) or it has to re-verify them from scratch.

See [Guidelines for Disabling Indexes and Constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177456.aspx) and [Non-trusted constraints and performance](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2008/01/12/non-trusted-constraints-and-performance.aspx).

Unless you did some **solid** measurements that demonstrated that the constraint verification of the DELETE operation are a performance bottleneck, let the engine do its work.

Comment: Just to have some real numbers: deleting 10M records out of a 12M table was actually 2 minutes slower with 1 temporarily deactivated constraint than it was with it activated (12:18 vs 10:28) - SQL-Server

Comment: In some situations, like seeding a domain table on DB recreate, it is required and OK to disable FK checks, because if you find someone has somehow added a lookup item with the incorrect code value, you have to delete that item and recreate it with both correct code and text value.

Answer (score 6):

Do not under any circumstances disable the constraints. This is an extremely stupid practice. You cannot maintain data integrity if you do things like this. Data integrity is the first consideration of a database because without it, you have nothing.

The correct method is to delete from the child tables before trying to delete the parent record. You are probably timing out because you have set up cascading deltes which is another bad practice in a large database.

Comment: It can be very useful in certain situations when you really know what you are doing and make sure that all constraints are satisfied at the end of the transaction. For example, SqlBulkCopy ignores constraints by default, which makes sense when you think about it.

Comment: @chris, the key phrase there is really know what you are doing. Genrally these people are not asking how to disable the constraints onteh internet.

Comment: And if you want to truncate the ENTIRE database?

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old thread, but I landed here when my row deletes were blocked by foreign key constraints.  In my case, my table design permitted "NULL" values in the constrained column.  In the rows to be deleted, I changed the constrained column value to "NULL" (which does not violate the Foreign Key Constraint) and then deleted all the rows.

Comment: You can even make the database engine take care of that, with the `ON DELETE SET NULL` constraint. See [ALTER TABLE table_constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-table-constraint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to delete all records from both tables because it was all test data. I used **SSMS GUI** to temporarily disable a FK constraint, then I ran a DELETE query on both tables, and finally I re-enabled the FK constraint.

To disable the FK constraint:

1. expand the database object [1]
2. expand the dependant table object [2]
3. expand the 'Keys' folder
4. right click on the foreign key
5. choose the 'Modify' option
6. change the 'Enforce Foreign Key Constraint' option to 'No'
7. close the 'Foreign Key Relationships' window
8. close the table designer tab
9. when prompted confirm save changes
10. run necessary delete queries
11. re-enable foreign key constraint the same way you just disabled it.

[1] in the 'Object Explorer' pane, can be accessed via the 'View' menu option, or key F8

[2] if you're not sure which table is the dependant one, you can check by right clicking the table in question and selecting the 'View Dependencies' option.

Comment: I found it easier to just delete the tables in object explorer and let Batch recreate them (run the delete again for the tables that failed to delete because of FK constraints.).

Answer (score 5):

You can disable all of the constaints on your database by the following line of code:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

and after the runing your update/delete command, you can enable it again as the following:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the way to disable foreign key checks in MySQL. Not relevant to OP's question since they use MS SQL Server, but google search results do turn this up so here's for reference:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

**/* Run your script */**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

See if this helps, This is for ignoring the `foreign key` checks.
But deleting disabling this is very bad practice.

Comment: This question is about SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: syntax is invalid in sql server

Answer (score 2):

On all tables with foreign keys pointing to this one, use:

```
ALTER TABLE MyOtherTable NOCHECK CONSTRAINT fk_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily disable constraints on a table T-SQL, SQL Server

[MSSQL](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLDisableConstraints.aspx)

```
  ALTER TABLE TableName NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
  
  ALTER TABLE TableName CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
  
  ALTER TABLE TableName NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_Table_RefTable
  
  ALTER TABLE TableName CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_Table_RefTable
```

[ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/cannot-truncate-table-because-it-is-being-referenced-by-a-foreign-key-constraint)

```
  DELETE FROM TableName
  
  DBCC CHECKIDENT ('TableName', RESEED, 0)
```

[MySql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/cannot-truncate-table-because-it-is-being-referenced-by-a-foreign-key-constraint)

```
  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; -- Disable foreign key checking. 

  TRUNCATE TABLE [YOUR TABLE]; 

  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe disable and re-enable constraints:

http://sqlforums.windowsitpro.com/web/forum/messageview.aspx?catid=60&threadid=48410&enterthread=y

Answer (score -1):

For the testing purpose only, I used the following command in MySQL to delete only one record from a table that has foreign key references.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; -- Disabling foreign key checks before running the following query.
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = id_to_delete; -- Deleting a record from a table that has foreign key reference.
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1; -- Enabling foreign key checks after running the above query.
```

Comment: The question is about MS-SQL. Despite your comment your answer doesn't fits here