# Please recommend the best bulk-delete option

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.1.4. I've 3 tables: one being the core (table1), others are dependents (table2,table3). I inserted 70000 records in table1 and appropriate related records in other 2 tables. As I'd used CASCADE, I could able to delete the related records using DELETE FROM table1; It works fine when the records are minimal in my current PostgreSQL version. When I've a huge volume of records, it tries to delete all but there is no sign of deletion progress for many hours! Whereas, bulk import, does in few minutes. I wish to do bulk-delete in reasonable minutes. I tried TRUNCATE also. Like, TRUNCATE table3, table2,table1; No change in performance though. It just takes more time, and no sign of completion! From the net, I got few options, like, deleting all constraints and then recreating the same would be fine. But, no query seems to be successfully run over 'table1' when it's loaded more data!
Please recommend me the best solutions to delete all the records in minutes.

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
        t1_id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        disp_name       TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        last_updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
        UNIQUE(disp_name)
    ) WITHOUT OIDS;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX disp_name_index on table1(upper(disp_name));

CREATE TABLE table2 (
        t2_id           SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        t1_id   INTEGER REFERENCES table1 ON DELETE CASCADE,
        type    TEXT
    ) WITHOUT OIDS;

CREATE TABLE table3 (
        t3_id           SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        t1_id   INTEGER REFERENCES table1 ON DELETE CASCADE,
        config_key      TEXT,
        config_value    TEXT
    ) WITHOUT OIDS;
```

Regards,
Siva.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @Siva, I suggest you read the comments on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679854/postgresql-disabling-constraints

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.1.4? That's very old and slow. Upgrade to at least version 8.3, older versions are EOL. Version 9.1 is already available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an index on the columns on the child tables which reference the parent table:

on table2 create an index on the t1_id column

on table3 create an index on the t1_id column

that should speed things up slightly.

And/or, don't bother with the `on delete cascade`, make a delete stored procedure which deletes first from the child tables and then from the parent table, it may be faster than letting postgresql do it for you.

Comment: Hi Michael. I removed the CASCADE constraint, and it seems to be working great for me. However I was asked to retain the CASCADE! I tested the bulk delete with CASCADE on PostgreSQL 8.1.4 and 9.0. In 9.0, it works like a charm. In 8.1.4 which is in production, it takes unacceptable and uncertain amount of time. Is there any solution to retain CASCADE and achieve bulk delete with my tables and constraints mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

> In SQL, the **TRUNCATE TABLE** statement is a Data Definition Language
>   (DDL) operation that marks the extents of a table for deallocation
>   (empty for reuse). The result of this operation quickly removes all
>   data from a table, **typically bypassing a number of integrity
>   enforcing mechanisms**.
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncate_(SQL)

So truncate should be very fast. In your case, it looks like that you have a transaction which is not committed nor rollbacked. In that case your delete transaction will never finish.

To solve this problem, you should check your active transactions in your database. The easiest way (at least under SQL Server, it works) is to write "ROLLBACK COMMIT;" into the query window and execute it. If it executes without throwing an error, it means that there were actually an active transaction. If there is no active transaction remaining, it will give you an error.

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that you miss some indices on the database too.

If you issue the delete command from psql console, just hit Ctrl-C - the transaction will get interrupted and psql should inform you which query was being executed when you interrupted it.

Then use EXPLAIN to check why the query takes so long.

I had a similar situation recently and adding an index solved the problem.

Comment: If I remove CASCADE from my child tables, bulk deletion is working fine. Is there any reason why CASCADE takes uncertain amount of time when database is loaded with huge volume of data?

Comment: It may wait for other transactions to complete - on busy systems it may even be impossible to perform such a delete due to transaction timeout. Or it may still be an index-related issue.