# Why CASCADE constraint is preventing any operation on tables having bulk records?

Tags: sql, postgresql

As I had raised a question here at [Please recommend the best bulk-delete option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172101/please-recommend-the-best-bulk-delete-option), CASCADE constraint is the one that prevents me to delete the records in all the tables when they were loaded with bulk records.

Is there any reason for why CASCADE takes time when DELETE FROM table1; Or TRUNCATE table1 CASCADE is attempted?

FYI, I'm using PostgreSQL 8.1.4. Though outdated, when I remove CASCADE constraint in my tables (listed in the top link), both DELETE and TRUNCATE queries work fine.

However, CASCADE is what I needed! I can't just remove the constraint. Please help me on this.

Comment: I couldn't even able to drop the constraints when the tables are loaded with bulk records! How strange the version of postgresql is!

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Of course a DELETE will take longer if it needs to delete all related rows due to the CASCADEd constraint. And you should **really**, **really** upgrade. At least to the latest 8.1 version (which is 8.1.23)

Answer (score 1):

A common mistake is a missing index on the column of the foreign key. When deleting one row from the referenced table, all refering rows have to be found. Witout an index each row will lead to a SLOW sequential scan. With an index - easy and fast.

Perhaps this is your problem.

Comment: On PostgreSQL any foreign key target has to have a unique index.  You cannot specify a foreign key target where you don't have one.  That can't be the problem.  See my point above about the tradeoff between a single sequential scan on PostgreSQL and thousands of index scans....

Comment: @ChrisTravers, I am pretty sure "missing index on the column of the foreign key" means the referencing column. Foreign key = local side, unique key = remote side.

Comment: @ChrisTravers: You are right, the _target_ needs an unique index. However I wrote about the other side.

Answer (score 0):

Using cascade delete is a very poor idea! You have now discovered why. It siomply takes too long if large numbers of records are deleted.  You should correctly delete by starting with the child records first. If you are deleting a large number of records, you may need to write a script to delete in batches to avoid locking and taking too long for one command.

Let me explain why it gets slower. Suppose you want to delete 1000 records from the parent table, called TableA. There are three child tables involved. TableB averages 10 records per parent record. TableC averages 5 records per parent record. TableD averages 100 records per parant record. So your delete of 1000 records in Table A actually involves deleting 115000 records. Now suppose you were deleting 10,000 records from tableA, now your cascade delete will delete 1,150,000 records. Now in most databases, a parent table could have considerably more than three related tables (we have one with over 100 FKS). If we were to allow a cascade delete on our databases and someone tried to deleted 1000 records, they would end up deleting hundreds of millions of records.

Comment: Those records still have to be deleted anyway.  So that doesn't explain why deleting from child records is faster.  I went ahead and answered that part above.

Comment: Because you don't have to do it all in one transaction locking many tables, you can do it is batches.

Answer (score 0):

ON CASCADE DELETE on small operations, but it performs poorly on large ones.  To understand why we have to look at what is going on behind the scenes: On PostgreSQL we use triggers.

So if we delete from the parent table, for every row we delete, it goes and deletes on the child table as well.  This happens for each row deleted.  Now, note, that sequential scans are relatively cheap in PostgreSQL so you may be forcing a large number of index scans when a single sequential scan would be a lot faster.

So suppose on table 1 we are deleting 1000 records, and this means on table 2 we are deleting 10000 records.  If we do this right, we go and we delete from table 2, performing *a single scan* to do it.  Might take a few seconds on good hardware.  Then we go and delete from the parent record and this is fast.  Good, right?

Now suppose we rely on triggers to do the deletion.....

Scan through table 1, for each of 1000 rows we delete, scan through table 2's index, delete 10 rows, go to next.  We entirely lose any help we could get from the OS's prefetch routines, and we substitute a lot of redundant, random page reads for a much smaller number of sequential reads.  Now we are spending a lot of time waiting for disk platters to turn and heads to move.  Ouch......

ON DELETE CASCADE triggers have their place.  They work fine if we are just deleting from a few records.  But they fall apart very fast on bulk deletions.  Wrap all your deletions in a transaction, and delete from child tables first, and it will be far faster.