# sqlalchemy import export failing on IntegrityError

Tags: import, sqlalchemy

I'm writing an sqlalchemy import/export script using the serializer dumps and loads.
The export works, but I have problems with the import, mainly due to foreign key issues.
I'm using sorted_tables to get the list of tables sorted based on dependencies and this makes sure I won't have cross tables foreign key issues but is there something similar to handle internal foreign keys (a table pointing to itself)?

I'm basically thinking about 2 possible solutions:

1. Find a way to sort the rows based on the dependencies
2. Disable all constraints -> insert the data -> enable all constraints
   again

but I'm not sure how to do this properly...

a table example:

```
class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = "t_employee"

    id = sa.Column(Identifier, sa.Sequence('%s_id_seq' % __tablename__), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    first_name = sa.Column(sa.String(30))
    last_name = sa.Column(sa.String(30))
    manager_id  = sa.Column(Identifier, sa.ForeignKey("t_employee.id", ondelete='SET NULL'))
```

and here is my script:

```
def export_db(tar_file):
    print "Exporting Database. This may take some time. Please wait ..."

    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    tables = Base.metadata.tables

    with tarfile.open(tar_file, "w:bz2") as tar:
        for tbl in tables:
            print "Exporting table %s ..." % tbl
            table_dump = dumps(engine.execute(tables[tbl].select()).fetchall())

            ti = tarfile.TarInfo(tbl)
            ti.size = len(table_dump)
            tar.addfile(ti, StringIO(table_dump))

    print "Database exported! Exiting!"

    exit(0)

def import_db(tar_file):
    print "Importing to Database. This may take some time. Please wait ..."

    print "Dropping all tables ..."
    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)

    print "Creating all tables ..."
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    tables = Base.metadata.sorted_tables

    with tarfile.open(tar_file, "r:bz2") as tar:
        for tbl in tables:
            try:
                entry = tar.getmember(tbl.name)
                print "Importing table %s ..." % entry.name
                fileobj = tar.extractfile(entry)
                table_dump = loads(fileobj.read(), Base.metadata, db)
                for data in table_dump:
                    db.execute(tbl.insert(), strip_unicode(dict(**data)))
            except:
                traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
                exit(0)
        db.commit()

    print "Database imported! Exiting!"

    exit(0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For mass dumps, the standard technique is to disable constraints, do the import, then re-enable them.  You'll also get much faster performance on the inserts.

Comment: That's great, but how do I do that in sqlalchemy? any simple way?

Comment: you need to emit the appropriate SQL instructions which achieves this.  For example, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2681413/34549) illustrates that on Postgresql you can use the command "SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED".  Another approach is to use SQLAlchemy to reflect all the constraints, then DROP them explictly, then recreate them - you can lift some ideas from the recipe [here](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/DropEverything) which might help with that.

Comment: thanks, it does look like a possible direction although it strikes me odd that this is the simplest way. I will go with this approach if I won't find anything simpler.

Comment: Thanks @zzzeek, I ended up using the technique you suggested