# Disabling foreign key constraint, still can't truncate table? (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints

I have a table called PX_Child that has a foreign key on PX_Parent.  I'd like to temporarily disable this FK constraint so that I can truncate PX_Parent.  I'm not sure how this goes however.

I've tried these commands

```
ALTER TABLE PX_Child NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

ALTER TABLE PX_Parent NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

(truncate commands)

ALTER TABLE PX_Child CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

ALTER TABLE PX_Parent CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

But the truncate still tells me it can't truncate PX_Parent because of a foreign key constraint.  I've looked all around the net and can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong, sorry for the basic nature of this question.

Comment: Looks like Kalen Delaney was inadvertently responsible for starting this idea off. [Here she clarifies](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29927698/cant-truncate-table.aspx) "you have to drop the referencing constraint in order to truncate the table."

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can't truncate the table if there is any foreign key referencing it, including disabled constraints.  You either need to drop the foreign key constraints or use the `DELETE` command.

Comment: See my (5 years later) answer below for how to quickly generate the `DROP CONSTRAINT` and `ADD CONSTRAINT` SQL

Comment: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint. (Delete is not working either)

Answer (score 22):

There is an easier-ish way. I was faced with the same problem and found this solution:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3347/drop-and-recreate-all-foreign-key-constraints-in-sql-server/

If you just run this query in your DB, it will generate the T-SQL you need to include before/after your sproc, in order to delete and then restore any foreign key constraints.

Don't worry  about trying to understand this query itself.

```
CREATE TABLE #x -- feel free to use a permanent table
(
  drop_script NVARCHAR(MAX),
  create_script NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

DECLARE @drop   NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'',
        @create NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

-- drop is easy, just build a simple concatenated list from sys.foreign_keys:
SELECT @drop += N'
ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(cs.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(ct.name) 
    + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(fk.name) + ';'
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS fk
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS ct
  ON fk.parent_object_id = ct.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS cs 
  ON ct.[schema_id] = cs.[schema_id];

INSERT #x(drop_script) SELECT @drop;

-- create is a little more complex. We need to generate the list of 
-- columns on both sides of the constraint, even though in most cases
-- there is only one column.
SELECT @create += N'
ALTER TABLE ' 
   + QUOTENAME(cs.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(ct.name) 
   + ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(fk.name) 
   + ' FOREIGN KEY (' + STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.name)
   -- get all the columns in the constraint table
    FROM sys.columns AS c 
    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkc 
    ON fkc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
    AND fkc.parent_object_id = c.[object_id]
    WHERE fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
    ORDER BY fkc.constraint_column_id 
    FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, N'')
  + ') REFERENCES ' + QUOTENAME(rs.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(rt.name)
  + '(' + STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.name)
   -- get all the referenced columns
    FROM sys.columns AS c 
    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkc 
    ON fkc.referenced_column_id = c.column_id
    AND fkc.referenced_object_id = c.[object_id]
    WHERE fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
    ORDER BY fkc.constraint_column_id 
    FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, N'') + ');'
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS fk
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS rt -- referenced table
  ON fk.referenced_object_id = rt.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS rs 
  ON rt.[schema_id] = rs.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS ct -- constraint table
  ON fk.parent_object_id = ct.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS cs 
  ON ct.[schema_id] = cs.[schema_id]
WHERE rt.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND ct.is_ms_shipped = 0;

UPDATE #x SET create_script = @create;

PRINT @drop;
PRINT @create;

/*
EXEC sp_executesql @drop
-- clear out data etc. here
EXEC sp_executesql @create;
*/
```

Generates a bunch of:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Whatever] DROP CONSTRAINT....
--
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Whatever] ADD CONSTRAINT....
```

Comment: bad advice: "Don't worry about trying to understand this query itself". Never run anything gotten off the net without understanding it

Comment: True, but it wasn't a production version of the DB

Comment: There is a difference between understanding how a query works and making sure it won't do any harm. The latter is almost always easier.

Comment: Thank you so much for this script! Would have taken a while to figure out myself. While I do understand it, I totally agree, you do not have to understand it to use it. Just make sure the code it generates is correct before executing it.

Comment: The fact that this mess of dynamic sql is necessary to simply execute a TRUNCATE TABLE is revolting.

Comment: As written this doesn't properly recreate constraints with 'ON DELETE CASCADE` rules. It's a simple fix, change the line `FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, N'') + ');'` to `FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, N'') + ') ON DELETE ' + REPLACE(fk.delete_referential_action_desc, '_', ' ') + ';'`

Comment: Note that the `PRINT @drop` and `PRINT @create` statements will truncate in SQL Management Studio. If you want these full values you will need to `SELECT * FROM #x` and then copy values from the two resulting columns. Even then I ended up having to `DECLARE @tempCreate NVARCHAR(MAX); SELECT @tempCreate = create_script from #x; EXEC sp_executesql @tempCreate;` for my create statement.

Comment: This script didn't work for my tables, it must have missed something.

Comment: As Tyler said it will truncate the text if it's too long. Just tried in SQL Ops Studio (now known as Azure Data Studio) with same truncation.  Simply adding `select @drop union all select @create` at the end of the script will solve the problem.

Comment: If you receive an error "Cannot resolve the collation conflict..." after making the change suggested by @JasonLarke, then you can add " collate database_default" to the end of the query.  See https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/590

Answer (score 7):

SQL server will not let you truncate the table while the constraint exists, even if it's disabled.
Drop the constraint and re-create it after truncating the table.
Or just drop and re-create the tables, whichever is easier to do in your application.

Comment: What do you mean it's not a transactional command? You can roll it back just fine. `CREATE TABLE Blah(a int); INSERT Blah VALUES(1); SELECT * FROM Blah; BEGIN TRAN; TRUNCATE TABLE Blah; SELECT * FROM Blah; ROLLBACK TRAN SELECT * FROM Blah; DROP TABLE Blah`. Truncate works by deallocating entire pages rather than removing rows, but it's still transactional.

Comment: @Emtucifor: Oops, seems like I misinterpreted the documentation you you're right! I removed that piece of misinformation.

Comment: @Emtucifor, @pgroke, in a way you are both correct as the standard allows for TRUNCATE to be non-transactional, but implementations are allowed to make it transaction. Hence TRUNCATE as defined doesn't promise a rollback can be done, but SqlServer (and Postgres) adds that promise beyond the standard.

Comment: @Jon Thanks for clarifying. Let me rephrase. **In SQL Server**, truncate is transactional.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such option to truncate table while foreign key constraint but we can use some trick like

```
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table2] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_table2_table1]
    GO
    truncate table [table1]
GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table2]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_table2_table1] FOREIGN KEY([FKId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[table1] ([ID])
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table2] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_table2_table1]
    GO
```