# best script can do easily truncate all tables in the database using Microsoft Sql Server (1 Command)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have here example can truncate table

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="TRUNCATE TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL";
```

but the error says.

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'NOCHECK'.

how to create a script which can truncate all the data in the tables in just 1 command, and can force to truncate with `FOREIGN KEY`

Thanks

Comment: Use single quotes not double quotes.

Comment: same error.. even if its single or double

Comment: `TRUNCATE TABLE` does *not* have any of those options. Which is what the error says too. Have you tried to truncate a single table with that command?

Comment: i can do truncate in just table.  but the question is how can i truncate all the table in the my main database?

Comment: No you can't, not with *that* command

Comment: Might want to check how to do it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/156813/6492765 .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you truncate all tables in a database using TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155246/how-do-you-truncate-all-tables-in-a-database-using-tsql)

Comment: TSQL or SQL is that same?

Comment: @MK_ the first link doesn't show *truncation*, the second will fail if there are foreign keys, even disabled

Comment: @DevGeorge, you can't just create new `TRUNCATE TABLE` syntax to do what you want. One cannot truncate a table referenced by a foreign key. You'll need to drop the referencing FKs, truncate, and recreate the constraints.

Comment: im finding new solution for the question... easily fast understand.

Comment: @DevGeorge if you don't know that difference *stop right now* before you nuke a production database. Why do you want to delete all data anyway? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? There are probably less risky ways to do it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the main purpose is that. after the database. i want to make it empty all the data to that database.. thanks..!

Comment: @DevGeorge for example, if you want to create an empty database for deployment, you can *script it*. Or export a dacpac without any data. Or create a Database project with SSDT, which would also allow you to version control the database

Comment: @DevGeorge no that's not the main purpose. That's the initial statement. The question is *why* do you want to do that? What is the problem to which you thing rimrafing the database is the solution? And why did you try random hints instead of eg, checking the documentation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843806/disabling-foreign-key-constraint-still-cant-truncate-table-sql-server-2005

Comment: I'd like to add that you CANNOT truncate with the foreign keys on. You can only delete from the tables if you turn the constraints off for the time being. @PanagiotisKanavos is right, if you want to just get the schema to somewhere youc an just script it without data. What do you really want to achieve?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i just follow my boss. he said that after i back up the database.  i need to empty the database exist.. so thats why .

Comment: any suggestion for that..?? possible to fix it ?

Comment: As @MK_ has already commented, here is how you do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155246/how-do-you-truncate-all-tables-in-a-database-using-tsql/156813#156813