# Comma separated list in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to loop through comma separated list in SQL? I have a list of ID's and I need to pass these ID's to a stored procedure. I CANNOT alter the stored procedure. I need to figure out how to execute the SP for each id. Give me some ideas, I can carry on from there.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to call the stored procedure for EACH ID seperately? What language are you working outside of SQL?

Comment: If you can't alter the stored, why not call it multiple times?

Comment: SQL Server 2008-yes I want to call the stored procedure for each id as I cannot alter the SP itself. I have execute the SQL query. There is no other language used.

Comment: +1 for "Give me some ideas, I can carry on from there."

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
declare @S varchar(20)
set @S = '1,2,3,4,5'

while len(@S) > 0
begin
  --print left(@S, charindex(',', @S+',')-1)
  exec YourSP left(@S, charindex(',', @S+',')-1)
  set @S = stuff(@S, 1, charindex(',', @S+','), '')
end
```

Try on SE Data: [Walk the string](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66016)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: So much better than splits & temp tables & cursors combo.