# How to Drop a table with it's all Foreign Keys Constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there is any way in TSQL to Drop a table with it's all Foreign Keys Constraint? I have search a lot but could not find any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/cannot-truncate-table-because-it-is-being-referenced-by-a-foreign-key-constraint

Comment: check for the answers in above link rather than the question

Answer (score 1):

To get all foreign key relationships referencing your table, you could use this SQL (if you're on SQL Server 2005 and up):

Use Below Script

`SELECT * 
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE referenced_object_id = object_id(TableName)`

`SELECT 
    'ALTER TABLE ' + OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) + 
    ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + name
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE referenced_object_id = object_id(TableName)`