# Remove content from SQL Server tables

Tags: sql-server

I have several tables with content. Is there a way how I can remove all the content without removing the keys (primary key, foreign key etc.) ?

When I say truncate or delete it obviously returns an error.

> Cannot truncate table 'login' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

Comment: What do you want to do with that foreign key constraint?  Maybe you should truncate the table referencing this one before truncating this one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot truncate table because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/cannot-truncate-table-because-it-is-being-referenced-by-a-foreign-key-constraint)

Answer (score 2):

You're right, you cannot run truncate table on an table which uses an foreign key. But you can run a normal delete on the table itself.

The only thing you should take care of is the order.

For example:
You have a table `users` and a table `users_log` where you store all users logins.
You cannot run the delete on the `users` table if still rows from `users_log` referencing them.
If you delete all rows from `users_log` and afterwards deleting the rows from `users` everything should be fine.

In this particular example, this code will work:

```
DELETE FROM users_log
DELETE FROM users
```

While this won work:

```
DELETE FROM users
DELETE FROM users_log -- which has a foreign key constraint on users
```