# Unable to truncate table - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I get the following error.

> Could not drop object 'tablename' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

This means there are references for the table I want to truncate. Then I use to remove all constraint for all table using following queries.

```
use mydb

EXEC sp_MSforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"

truncate table mytable.
```

But it's not working, please assist.

Comment: That already answer before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/cannot-truncate-table-because-it-is-being-referenced-by-a-foreign-key-constraint

Comment: You mention you want to **truncate** your table, but the error says you cannot **drop** the table...... what now? Truncate or drop ??

Comment: And `NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL` does *not* remove or disable constraints. What are you actually trying to do and what code did you use? The text of the question contradicts your code. What is the *actual* problem you are trying to fix by using truncate and removing constraints?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried both truncate and drop but both not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NO, don't use `sp_MSforeachtable` and it's not documented or supported. Rather, run command `sp_help mytable` or `sp_helptext mytable` and see which all table referencing table `mytable`. Drop the FK constraint for moment and then run your `TRUNCATE` command and other processing.

Once everything is fine, re-create the FK constraint again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this but you should not use this in Production environment.
This code will truncate all the tables in a specific database.

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'  
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? DISABLE TRIGGER ALL'  
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'DELETE FROM ?'  
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'  
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? ENABLE TRIGGER ALL' 
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
    FROM SYS.IDENTITY_COLUMNS
    JOIN SYS.TABLES ON SYS.IDENTITY_COLUMNS.Object_ID = SYS.TABLES.Object_ID
    WHERE SYS.TABLES.Object_ID = OBJECT_ID(''?'') AND SYS.IDENTITY_COLUMNS.Last_Value IS NULL)
    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(''?''), ''TableHasIdentity'') = 1
    DBCC CHECKIDENT (''?'', RESEED, 0) WITH NO_INFOMSGS'
```