# Cannot truncate table because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint using ExecuteSqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

i want to clear data from this table from entity framework

```
db2.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [destDepartments]");
```

but i have this error

***Cannot truncate table 'destDepartments' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.'***

so how i can do this from EF?

Comment: EF or not, `TRUNCATE` is not allowed here for the reasons mentioned in the error. Use `DELETE` instead as that will ensure you don't break referential integrity.

Comment: You couldn't do it even if you ran the sql command directly in SSMS. to be able to truncate a table, it must have no tables referencing it with foreign keys.

Comment: You want to delete all the data from this table? The error says that the data in this able is being referenced by some other table via ForeignKey. So you first need to clear the other table.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i already delete the other table in the previous line in my code but i don't know what the wrong

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/cannot-truncate-table-because-it-is-being-referenced-by-a-foreign-key-constraint

Comment: Instead of truncating the table why not use `DELETE FROM destDepartments` command.?

Comment: IT WORKS WELL!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are restrictions on when you can use `TRUNCATE TABLE`. One of them is that the table cannot be involved in foreign key relationships with other tables in the database. Use `DELETE FROM [destDepartments]` instead.

`TRUNCATE TABLE` and `DELETE FROM` are [not functionally equivalent](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/difference-between-truncate-delete-and-drop-in-sql-server1) but the latter will allow you to clear a table that is related to other tables in the database (provided referential integrity is maintained).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to get rid of any references before deleting the table.

Comment: It's not that there are related records, it's that there is a foreign key relationship at all. Even if there were no related records, `TRUNCATE TABLE` would error because of the foreign key.