# How to Clear all Values in MySQL DB in all tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an application with a MySQL Database. The application is currently under testing. After testing I want to delete all testing data in the database(but keep all tables as it is). I want to refresh all tables in the DB. If i just delete values from the DB, the AUTO_INCREMENT columns do not start from 1.

How do I refresh the DB so all values are gone?

Comment: why not just drop and recreate the database ?

Comment: _the AUTO_INCREMENT columns do not start from 1..._ => `ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1`

Comment: What about Standard docs ? it says, if you truncate the table, the auto increment starts from 1 [Link to Standard docs](https://oracle-base.com/articles/mysql/mysql-how-truncate-table-affects-auto-increment)

Comment: I agree with @SudiptaMondal: just drop and recreate the database. Much faster. Also _"If i just delete values from the DB, the AUTO_INCREMENT columns do not start from 1"_ is a big red flag. Why would you care at which value your auto increment starts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to **truncate** all your tables.
after truncating all your Auto Increment starts from 1 instead of where you left.
[here is the link for more info](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-truncate-table/)

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;
```

Comment: Truncate won't always work (especially when there's other tables relying on the truncated table via FK's).

Comment: Agree with you,you cannot truncate a table which has an FK constraint on it. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/cannot-truncate-table-because-it-is-being-referenced-by-a-foreign-key-constraint)