# How to fix Error clearing table? SQL command

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, datagridview

```
private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int n;
    n = dgBooks.Rows.Count;

    if (n != 0)
    {
            string SqlText = "TRUNCATE TABLE [Books]";
            MyExecuteNonQuery(SqlText);
    }

}
```

MyExecuteNonQuery class sql command execution

Error:"Cannot truncate table 'Books' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint."

Comment: It's a SQL issue, not c# though

Comment: This is a good example of the error message telling you exactly what the problem is. Some other table in your database has a foreign key to the table `books`. Look for tables with a field called `book_id`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot truncate table because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/cannot-truncate-table-because-it-is-being-referenced-by-a-foreign-key-constraint)

Answer (score 1):

The [foreign key constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) is telling your that at lease one other table has a relationship to your Books table. AKA you cannot truncate the Books table, other table(s) depend on it's data. You have to remove the foreign key constraint.

Comment: Even if you truncate the other table, you still need to remove the constraint because the mechanism for checking the constraint is circumvented by `TRUNCATE`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. `DROP` the foreign key constraint on the table. -

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_drop_constraint.asp

2. `TRUNCATE` the table -

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_drop_table.asp

3. Re-Add the `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT` -

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

In that order